# Not able to delete SQLite records using WHERE clause

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my app, I am using an SQLite database for storing values. I want to delete some records in the database using the `WHERE` clause.

Here is the function that I wrote:

```
public Cursor deleteSomeDetails(String user_login_name, String product_code,
                                         SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("delete from "
                                 + RaisePoProductDetails.NewUSerInfo.TABLE_NAME
                                 + " where user_login_name = '"
                                 + user_login_name + "' and productcode ='"
                                 + product_code + "'", null);

    return cursor;
}
```

The records are still not deleting. Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean deleteSomeDetails(SQLiteDatabase db, String user_login_name, String product_code) {
    return db.delete(RaisePoProductDetails.NewUSerInfo.TABLE_NAME, "user_login_name=? and productcode=?", new String[] {user_login_name, product_code}) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below:

```
public void Delete_Bus(String bus_num)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_BUS+" WHERE "+"user_login_name"+"='"+user_login_name+"'");
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: what is this see my query clearly i am using where class and also and operator